# One of the ads isn't displaying

Tags: status-completed, advertising, bug, 404-not-found

An ad doesn't seem to be displaying properly. In fact, when I go to it, I get the following:

[image]

Here is the URL: **http://static2.theloungenet.com/Advertisers/**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 01 Oct 2010 00:12:56 GMT
...
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
...
```

Notice the MIME type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've tracked down this bad ad and destroyed it.  Let us know if you find another.